# how to upgrade openssl in apache webserver

Tags: apache, openssl, upgrade

we are using apache webserver ver 2.2.3 with open SSL version 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 (linux environment). We are required to upgrade the openSSL to the latest version for security reasons. I have following doubts

as per https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140605.txt, ver 0.9.8 should be upgraded to 0.9.8za. Please let me know if its ok to upgrade to 0.9.8za or we should go for 1.0.1h

what is the procedure of upgrading openssl which comes with apache webserver

Is it required to regenerate the keys and certificate again

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can update with below command

```
yum update openssl
```